# how to find the new line inside a cell in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to search for a word in a string in cell. 
Can someone please help me with finding out where the new line starts inside the cell and take the first word and write it in the adjacent cell [image]

Comment: The new line is indicated to the character by the (aptly named) ["New Line" character](http://www.asciitable.com/).  This can be represented in a formula by [`CHAR(10)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/char-function-bbd249c8-b36e-4a91-8017-1c133f9b837a), and then all you have to do is [find](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) it and take the next characters from the [mid](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)dle of the string.

Comment: If you have any *specific* issues when putting these together, please ask for assistance (keeping it a [mcve]) - and think about [ask] your question - e.g. include code you have already tried.  (This site is to help you learn to write your own code, not to ask for someone else to write it for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetFirstWord()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet8")     ' Change to your source sheet
    Dim aOriginalString As Variant
    Dim sNewString As String
    Dim iC As Long

    aOriginalString = Split(oWS.Range("A2").Value, vbLf)    ' Change range to your source range
    For iC = 0 To UBound(aOriginalString)
        If iC = UBound(aOriginalString) Then
            sNewString = sNewString & Split(aOriginalString(iC), " ")(0)
        Else
            sNewString = sNewString & Split(aOriginalString(iC), " ")(0) & vbLf
        End If
    Next
    oWS.Range("B2").Value = sNewString      ' Change range to your destination range

End Sub
```

You can make this a lot more clever by getting the source and destination range dynamically